# Building Dynamic jQuery Menu Using $(window).scrollTop();

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery but I'm trying to set things up so that when you scroll down past the global navigation at the top of the page a smaller menu with the same links pops out from the side. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var a = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (a >= 150){
                $('#sideNav a:eq(1)').animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
                $('#sideNav a:eq(2)').delay(100).animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
                $('#sideNav a:eq(3)').delay(200).animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
                $('#sideNav a:eq(4)').delay(300).animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
            } else if (a < 150){
                $('#sideNav a:eq(4)').animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
                $('#sideNav a:eq(3)').delay(100).animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
                $('#sideNav a:eq(2)').delay(200).animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
                $('#sideNav a:eq(1)').delay(300).animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first if statement works fine and the animations work but adding in the else if to make it disappear when you scroll back to the top seems to break it. The animations still work but they don't fire until a few seconds after the page has been scrolled to the appropriate place and they look slower and choppy. I think the problem is I need to check to see what state the menu is in and then stop the animations if it is already in that state but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your post, the problem is that you're animating elements over and over again. You can remedy this by adding a variable that you check *before* animating and reset *after* animating (inside the callback argument to [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var animating = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var a = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (a >= 150 && !animating){
            animating = true;
            $('#sideNav a:eq(1)').animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
            $('#sideNav a:eq(2)').delay(100).animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
            $('#sideNav a:eq(3)').delay(200).animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
            $('#sideNav a:eq(4)').delay(300).animate({'margin-right': '0', 'opacity': '1'}, 500, 
                 /* Called after animation has completed: */
                 function() { animating = false; });
        } else if (a < 150 && !animating){
            animating = true;
            $('#sideNav a:eq(4)').animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
            $('#sideNav a:eq(3)').delay(100).animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
            $('#sideNav a:eq(2)').delay(200).animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500);
            $('#sideNav a:eq(1)').delay(300).animate({'margin-right': '150', 'opacity': '0'}, 500, 
                function() { animating = false; });
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works! But now I've encountered another problem I hadn't noticed before... It seems as though $(window).scroll only calls the function when the screen begins to scroll, not any time the screen is scrolling. For example when I do one long scroll on my laptops trackpad from the top of the page the menu will often not pop up until I scroll a second time when it is already in an area below the .scrollTop() I specified. This happens vice versa when scrolling bottom to top. I'd like to have it check while scrolling but the jQuery API doesn't mention it and their demo seems to function the same.

Comment: @phantomspaceman: Hmm, something else you could try is the strategy outlined here: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/. Basically you check the scroll position every few milliseconds instead of on the scroll event.

Comment: Thanks for the link, managed to work something similar into what I was doing and it looks to be working as intended now!